# Is there a way of getting a decisecond value from millisecond value?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a timer in JS. I am getting the time left until the date and storing it in a variable called distance. I am then getting the time left in days, hours, minutes and seconds. I would like to know if there is a way to also get the deciseconds (second/10)

```
var days = Math.floor(distance / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
var hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24)) / (1000 * 60 * 60));
var minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);
```

Comment: What about `seconds / 10`?

Comment: @VLAZ I know, i want to do a calculation like ```var seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);``` to get the decisecond

Comment: what? why is there a `60` in there ...

Comment: @ECMC what is stopping you? You have the formula: `Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)` to get the deciseconds you need `Math.floor(((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000) / 10)` (which simplifies to `Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 100)`). But I don't see why you'd do that, since it's needless repetition. You already have the result of `Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000)`  : it's `seconds`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just continue according to the same logic:

```
var decis = Math.floor((distance % 1000) / 100);
```

So this will be a one-digit integer.

Comment: Although I am getting a 2 digit integer

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo. Corrected.